# Chi square for survival data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, survival

Can the chi-squared test be used for comparing survival curves between or among treatment groups? In the particular case of interest, there are 4 treatment groups.

Comment: Is your null hypothesis that there are no differences between the 4 survival curves?

Answer (score 3):

Not in any usual way; the chi-square test (at least, as that is commonly meant) is for categorical variables.

Please tell us what you are trying to do.